# Canvas image resizing makes file bigger

Tags: javascript, canvas, image-resizing, filesize

I'm implementing image upload, but before that, I want to do some resizing based on limits (eg. max-width, max-height, max-area). Problem is not resize image, but filesize.

I already gave up with quality, there was no visible differences in results gained from: Canvas, [Pica](https://github.com/nodeca/pica), [Hermite](https://github.com/viliusle/Hermite-resize), so i decided to go with offscreen canvas.

Filesize is much bigger problem, eg.: if I have PNG image, that is 345x518 (54.2kB) and I want it to fit into area 512x512, after resizing it into 341x512 jpeg (same aspect ratio), filesize became 171.7kB.

Resize function:

```
function _canvasImageGet(original, dims) {
  var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  canvas.width = dims.w;
  canvas.height = dims.h;
  canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(original, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  return canvas;
}
```

Is there any way, how can I get smaller or same filesize after resizing? It doesn't have to be using Canvas, but I will appreciate, if resizing will be on client. Thanks for all anwers.

Comment: Will depend on the image and what it contains. When you convert the image to a jpeg you can set the quality as the second argument. eg `canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg",quality)`  quality is in the range 0 < quality <= 1 where low values are lower quality.  This can make a big difference to the file size.

Answer (score 1):

Canvas and other libraries I have used are not using compression so after resizing, output file is naturally bigger than it was before. I have found exactly what I needed. [image-compressor](https://github.com/xkeshi/image-compressor) does resizing and compression and all it's done on client-side. There is another library [JIC](https://github.com/brunobar79/J-I-C), but it can't do resizing.